# Hi How to handle 302 response in dp:url-open()

Tags: xslt, ibm-datapower

Hi How to handle 302 response in dp:url-open(), and how to deleate ***all*** the request http headers before sending to back-end. those headers are dynamic.

Thanks,
Manoj.

Answer (score 0):

For(hypothetically) a Multi-Protocol Gateway, go in the "advanced" tab, switch the "Follow Redirects" option off. Then the 302 http response is treated just as any 2xx responses.

From that point on, you can create a GatewayScript code that test the error code (and if value == 302), then delete all headers.

The code would look something like this (please correct if I missed something):

```
var hm = require('header-metadata');

var all_Headers = hm.current.headers;

console.error(all_Headers);

if (hm.current.statusCode == 302) {
    for (var headerName in all_Headers) {
      hm.current.remove(headerName);
    }
}
```

Here are some good references for GatewayScript:

- Nice [IBM "playground" site](https://developer.ibm.com/datapower/datapower-playground/), click on "samples" for the cool part
- Official GatewayScript code documentation
  Specific part about [header deleting](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS9H2Y_7.6.0/com.ibm.dp.doc/headers_js.html#headers.remove) in GatewayScript
- I partially based my example on this [healthcheck](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS9H2Y_7.2.0/com.ibm.dp.doc/lbg_healthchecks_scenario_GSresponseevaluator.html) example